# Solve $\frac{\log(2x+1)-\log 4}{1-\log(3x+2)}=1$

Tags: calculus, logarithms

My attempt:$$\frac{\log(2x+1)-\log4}{1-\log(3x+2)}=1$$
$$\frac{\log(2x+1)-\log4}{\log10-\log(3x+2)}=\log10$$
$$\frac{\log\frac{(2x+1)}{4}}{\log\frac{10}{(3x+2)}}=\log10$$
$$\frac{\frac{(2x+1)}{4}}{\frac{10}{(3x+2)}}=10$$ 
$$\frac{(2x+1)}{4}=10\cdot\frac{10}{(3x+2)}$$(is this even correct ??)
$$\frac{(2x+1)}{4}=\frac{100}{(3x+2)}$$
$$(2x+1)100=4(3x+2)$$
$$200x+100=12x+8$$
$$200x+100=12x+8$$
$$188x=-92$$
$$x=-23/47$$
The solution is 2.

Comment: No, you can't do $\dfrac{\log a}{\log b}=\dfrac{a}{b}$

Comment: Thought so... Then what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\log(2x+1)-\log4}{1-\log(3x+2)}=1$$
becomes
$$
\log(2x+1)-\log4=1-\log(3x+2)
$$
that is
$$
\log\frac{2x+1}{4}=\log\frac{10}{3x+2}
$$
Can you go on from here? (I assume decimal logarithms.)

---

You can't go from

$$
\frac{\log a}{\log b}=\log c
$$
to
$$
\frac{a}{b}=c
$$
Try some values to convince you about this.

Comment: Solved it! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\log(2x+1)-\log4}{1-\log(3x+2)}=1$$
$$\frac{\log(2x+1)/4}{\log 10/(3x+2)}=1$$
$$\log(2x+1)/4=\log 10/(3x+2)$$
$$(2x+1)/4=10/(3x+2)$$
$$(2x+1)(3x+2)=40$$
$$6x^2+7x-38=0$$
$$x_{1,2}=\frac{-7\pm31}{12}:x_1=2,x_2=-\frac{19}{6}$$
in real field only $x_1=2$ is a solution

Comment: Do you think that $-19/6$ is a solution?

Comment: No, it's not, because if you insert it in 2x+1 or in 3x+2, you get a negative number and logarithm of a negative nuber does not exsist, so a nuber must be >0 and ≠1.